# The new nav pagination links are broken on the homepage

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, homepage, pagination

The new nav pagination links on the [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) are broken. Clicking on one will scroll to the top of the page, but the page does not change.

The links are defined in HTML like this:

```
<a href="/" title="go to page 2"> <span class="page-numbers">2</span> </a>
```

However, when using filters (e.g. [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)), the links work.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?layout=expanded&amp;page=2&‌​amp;pagesize=15" title="go to page 2"> <span class="page-numbers">2</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in build `2015.12.16.3985` (meta) and  `2015.12.16.3090` (main).

Comment: So a question about this fix: Is it intended that clicking a page number does not change the url, and refreshing returns you to page one no matter what page you're on? (If the answer is "no" then expect a bug report shortly.)

Comment: for the moment, yes. We might change that after we finish the anonymous version. To be clear, if you add `?page=2` it will take you to that page.

Comment: Oh, I've realized that. The part that bothers me is if I refresh on page 2, I return to page one. Even if I've explicitly added the `?page=2` to the url.

Comment: @Kendra yeah, that's a bit annoying (although I see no reason why you should)

Comment: The reason why I do is simple: If I'm not on meta for a couple days, I like to see what's happened while I've been gone, starting on the page with the most recent changes I've seen. When I get to the top of said page, I refresh to see if the list has changed before moving on. So very annoying. But if it's currently intended I'll just have to make do. Thanks!

Comment: @Sklivvz Adding `?page=2` doesn't seem to work either on Meta or regular Stack Overflow.