# Firefox: jump to a particular search results page not working?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I first started using Stack Overflow, it was possible to jump to the middle of a set of search results pages by modifying the URL.  e.g. Suppose I search for "Python numpy" and get 100 pages of results, I could jump to page 50 by modifying the URL and putting "50" in the right place.  With the current navigation, the page number is apparently stored in memory (or a hidden variable?) and does not seem accessible.  So is there a way to jump to a specific page of results?  If not, I think there should be.

Comment: It works for me, I just have to click on any page number other than the first one at the bottom of the results, then the URL changes format to the way you are describing. E.g Starting in the search box with "python question" goes to http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+question click on page 2 link at the bottom and the URL changes to http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=python%20question which can be edited to http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=571&tab=relevance&q=python%20question

Comment: Interesting.  I'm using Firefox, and the URL doesn't change as I page forward/backward through search results.

Comment: @JoeMalpass: I tried again today, on Chrome this time, and I still get the same result.  Is there some kind of browser setting that prevents displaying updated URLs in this situation?

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it is behaving that way. I'm also using Chrome - Version 48.0.2564.41 beta-m (64-bit).

Comment: @JoeMalpass: I'm using Chrome version 47.0.2526.73 m...I haven't updated to 48 yet...hopefully that would fix this problem.

Comment: You can manually create the page url and jump that way, but there's still a problem with this: If you refresh on page 50, you'll be sent back to page 1. I'm checking to see if this was already posted as a bug (I don't think it would be a dupe of your question here) before posting such myself. (Note: To manually create the page, I had to figure out the url form from inspecting the page select elements, then just picking the page number that I wanted. You may need to do the same.)

Comment: @kendra: I wondered if I could do that, but I had not tried. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I should note that just `?page=#` works, I didn't realize that until after my comment, and forgot to come back and update. It also appears that [this is completely intentional.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312499/the-new-nav-pagination-links-are-broken-on-the-homepage/312524?noredirect=1#comment284762_312524)

Comment: @kendra: so I finally got around to trying the querystring variable (in Chrome), and it didn't work for me if I have already searched for something, like `python`..  However, if I am just searching through questions with no tags selected, it does work.