# Not able to change page 2

Tags: bug, new-nav

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=votes
2. Click page 2 at bottom
3. Wait for the URL to change to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=votes i.e. without `&page=2`
4. Now manually add `&page=2` at the end of the URL in your browser window and hit enter
5. Wait for page to load

**Expectation**

- The question list should be of the second page
- Be able to change page manually

**Actual Result**

- The question list is of the first page
- Manually clicking on the page numbers at bottom not able to go to page 2

**Environment**

- Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Why I was doing it?**
I was trying to bookmark the page which needed page number

Comment: So, to clarify, when you click the page number did it change the question list and just not the URL or did nothing change? It's not 100% obvious from the wording of your question, and one is actually not a bug.

Comment: @Kendra The question list did not change. Updated question. Also why is one not a bug?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not able to reproduce the issue myself, on Chrome 48.0.2564.109 m Windows 7. You may want to add your browser information to the question so the devs have a better chance of reproducing. As well, do you have any extensions/plugins installed? Did you try this without those installed? Are you on the [new-nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312434/a-quick-new-nav-update)?

Comment: The URL not changing is 100% intended (and very annoying). I had asked a dev about it on a related question. Edit: Found it- Read through the comment chain [on this answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312524/2607247)

Comment: What do you mean by new nav?

Comment: I messed up the link on that comment, sorry- I've fixed it now, to point to one of the posts about new-nav.

Comment: @Kendra yes I am using the new nav

Comment: Simpler steps to reproduce: 1) Click [this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=votes&page=2) 2) Observe that you end up on page 1, even though the link URL says `page=2`.