# Unable to change page number manually entering page parameter in URL

Tags: bug, new-nav

Hopefully this question has already been answered, similar behavior of [Not able to change page 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316992/not-able-to-change-page-2) which hasn't been answered.

Maybe relates to the `new-nav` feature.

I try to skip to a specific page list of questions instead of starting from Page 1 and clicking links on the bottom, I manually pass the page number in the URL parameter (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?page=150 to go to page 150). This behavior worked last week, but now when passing a number to the `?page=` parameter the site returns Page 1. I have assured the page number I pass within an available range, even tried right-clicking "Copy link address" and modifying the `?page=` number.

Screenshots illustrating my senario:
[Manually entering page parameter into URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWpbV.jpg)
[Image of using page from link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ2XH.jpg)

Interestingly, this only happens when I am logged in as my user. If I logout of the site and pass a page number to the same URL, it goes to that requested page just fine.

Have tried both in Firefox and Chrome getting same results, on Mac Yosemite.